# Create a new instance of a div based on form input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, onsubmit

I have a list of buses that a user can choose to track.  The html looks like this:

```
<div class="bus-container">
    <div class="bus-heading">
        <h1>My Buses</h1>
        <svg width="15px" height="15px" class="add-bus"><use xlink:href="#plus"></use></svg>
    </div>
    <form class="hidden">
      <select name="company">
          <option value="greyhound">Greyhound</option>
          <option value="zippy">Zippy</option>
          <option value="carta">Carta</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Enter Bus Number" />
      <input type="text" name="route" placeholder="Enter the route" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <div class="bus active">
        <img src="img/greyhound.png" width="100" height="40" />
        <p class="bus-number">12345043</p>
        <p class="route">Jefferson</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bus active">
        <img src="img/zippy.png" width="100" height="40" />
        <p class="bus-number">12345043</p>
        <p class="route">Jefferson</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bus active">
        <img src="img/carta.png" width="100" height="4" />
        <p class="bus-number">12345043</p>
        <p class="route">Jefferson</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am wondering what is the best way to use Javascript to create a new instance of the `.bus` div when the user inputs their info and clicks submit.  I know I need to call on `onsubmit` function on the form and prevent the default click on the submit button itself.  But I am pretty clueless as to how to append the new `.bus` div based on the user's input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a re-usable function called within `onsubmit` handler for `form` element, passing `select` value, number and route as parameters

```
window.onload = function() {

  function addBus(company, number, route) {
    var buses = document.querySelectorAll(".bus");
    var curr = document.createElement("div");
    curr.setAttribute("class", "bus active");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "img/" + company + ".png";
    img.width = 100;
    img.height = 40;
    var p1 = document.createElement("p");
    p1.setAttribute("class", "bus-number");
    p1.innerHTML = number;
    var p2 = document.createElement("p");
    p2.setAttribute("class", "route");
    p2.innerHTML = route;
    curr.appendChild(img);
    curr.appendChild(p1);
    curr.appendChild(p2);
    if (buses.length) {
      buses[buses.length - 1].insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", curr.outerHTML)
    } else {
      document.forms[0].insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", curr.outerHTML)
    }
  }

  var obj = {
    company: "",
    number: "",
    route: ""
  };

  document.forms[0].onchange = function(e) {
    obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  }

  document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addBus(obj.company, obj.number, obj.route)
  }
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/mLz2pNROV3cSCPmnE2S1?p=preview

Comment: I the idea of the re-usable function above.  In this function, how do the form inputs get passed in?

Comment: @JordanBarber Add `required` attribute to `select` and `input` elements, at `onchange` event of `form` store values; at `onsubmit` event pass stored values to `addBus` function

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to create the new bus div and append it to it's container:

```
// get these from the form...
var newBusNumber = 123;
var newRoute = "Jefferson";

// create new bus div
var $busDiv = jQuery("<div></div>");
$busDiv.addClass("bus");
$busDiv.addClass("active");

// create img tag
var $img = jQuery("<img />");
$img.attr("src", "img/carta.png");
$img.attr("width", "100");
$img.attr("height", "4");

// create first paragraph tag
var $p1 = jQuery("<p></p>");
$p1.addClass("bus-number");
$p1.text(newBusNumber);

// create second paragraph tag
var $p2 = jQuery("<p></p>");
$p2.addClass("route");
$p2.text(newRoute);

// put the bus div pieces together
$busDiv.append($img);
$busDiv.append($p1);
$busDiv.append($p2);


// append the bus div to it's container
var $busContainer = jQuery(".bus-container");
$busContainer.append($busDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery AJAX.After successfull callback append whatever you want .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just clone the required 'bus', and append it to the container, something like that.

```
function addBus() {
  var id = document.querySelector('input[name="number"]').value; // the index of chosen bus;
  var bus = document.querySelectorAll(".bus")[id]; // get chosen bus
  var newBus = bus.cloneNode(true); // deep cloning of the existing 'bus'
  document.querySelector('.bus-container').appendChild(newBus); // add to the container
}
```